# Codeigniter SQL Join with multiple ON clauses?

Tags: sql, codeigniter, join

This is the SQL query displayed by codeigniter:

> SELECT * FROM (status_updates) JOIN friend_connections ON ((
>   status_updates.userid=friend_connections.userid) OR
>   (status_updates.userid=friend_connections.friend_id)) WHERE
>   status_updates.enabled = "1" AND friend_connections.enabled = "1"
>   ORDER BY status_updates.date desc, status_updates.time desc LIMIT 20

The Codeigniter commands i used were:

```
$this->db->from('status_updates');
$this->db->order_by("status_updates.date", "desc");
$this->db->order_by("status_updates.time", "desc");
$this->db->limit(20);
$this->db->join('status_updates', '((status_updates.userid=friend_connections.userid) OR (status_updates.userid=friend_connections.friend_id))');
```

What i'm trying to do is select everything in two tables, status_updates and friend_connections. status_updates has the one column userid which i want to match with either userid or friend_id from friend_connections. Can someone tell me how i can do this please?

Also i noticed that codeigniter removes the two opening parentheses after the ON command in the above sql query.

Comment: Sorry, but i've now been able to get it working. Instead of using the codeigniter sql commands, i wrote it manually.


'$sql = "SELECT * FROM (status_updates) JOIN friend_connections ON ((status_updates.userid=friend_connections.userid) OR (status_updates.userid=friend_connections.friend_id)) WHERE status_updates.enabled = "1" AND friend_connections.enabled = "1" ORDER BY status_updates.date desc, status_updates.time desc LIMIT 20";

**$status = $this->db->query($sql);**'

Comment: hi Bolu, can you add this as an answer and then accept that answer so it will be taken out of the "unanswered" questions page? thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy of your own answer in order to remove this from the unanswered stack:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (status_updates) JOIN friend_connections ON ((status_updates.userid=friend_connections.userid) OR (status_updates.userid=friend_connections.friend_id)) WHERE status_updates.enabled = "1" AND friend_connections.enabled = "1" ORDER BY status_updates.date desc, status_updates.time desc LIMIT 20";
$status = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Please don't upvote. It's not my answer.